# How to compile packages for Cygwin

Tags: c, ssh, cygwin, package

How is it possible to compile packages for Cygwin? I want to use the second factor authentication for SSH. So I need the packages libpam-otpw and otpw-bin for cygwin. Is is possible to compile these Debian packages for Cygwin, because the packages are not in the official cygwin sources.

http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/otpw.html

Comment: yes, it is generally possible if it is portable code. The concepts are all the same, but details can differ from package to package.

Comment: Is there a Tutorial or a HowTo? I just need this little Package to get it to work with SSH.

Comment: I was searching for tutorials some time ago, but without any success. But when you have cygwin installed and you are in cygwin shell, you can follow almost any linux tutorial or how-to.\